# Need help in parsing a JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am working on a file that has data in a JSON format but the JSON parser is unable to recognize the data due to the following

1-The objects are padded with an extra backslash

2-The object start and end braces are in quotes `{"menu":"{ }"}`

I used `replace()` function but it's clearing all of the blackslashes which is causing issues.

Sample data

```
{"menu": "{
 \"URL\": \"http:\\/\\/www.example.com\\/concepts\\/test\\/data\\/\",
 \"value\": \"File\",
  \"popup\":\"testfile\" 
  }"}
```

expected output

```
{"menu": {
"url": "http:\/\/www.example.com\/concepts\/test\/data\/",
"value": "File",
"popup":"testfile" 
}}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I would try `.replace('"\','"')` for the quotes (same for curly braces). but it's data dependent. Difficult to create a generic solution given that the internal logic of the file is trashed.

Comment: BTW no need to escape the slashes, so your first idea could very well work.

Comment: if the file is known, just try to perform replacements using notepad++ or a regex capable editor until the file is correct. If the file is generated by another tool, just hit the head of the guy who coded the tool with a stapler until the bug is fixed.

Comment: Are you certain that's `"\url\"` and not `\"url\"`?

Comment: My bad ..I corrected it.Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `menu` object is just JSON as a string and can be extracted pretty easily.

```
import json
inputjs = r"""{"menu": "{
 \"URL\": \"http:\\/\\/www.example.com\\/concepts\\/test\\/data\\/\",
 \"value\": \"File\",
  \"popup\":\"testfile\" 
  }"}"""

result = json.loads(inputjs.replace('\n', ''))
menu = result["menu"]
result = json.loads(menu);
json.dumps({'menu':result})
```

Comment: awesome .Thanks for your help.